# d3 on how to sum values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the data below:

```
[
  { id: 0, Department: "Civil", Value: "40000", Title:"Sustainability", ComID: "45", organisation: { City: "New York", ComID: 45, Country: "USA" } },
  { id: 1, Department: "Energy", Value: "82000", Title: "Wind Energy", ComID: "62", organisation: { City: "Paris" , ComID: 62, Country: "France" } },
  { id: 2, Department: "Medical", Value: "67000", Title: "Neuroscience", ComID: "21", organisation: { City: "Berlin", ComID: 21, Country: "Germany" } },
  { id: 3, Department: "Computer", Value: "100000", Title: "Security", ComID: "67", organisation: { City: "Amsterdam", ComID: 67, Country: "Holland" } }
]
```

the data is an array of about 100 objects like the ones above.

In the data I have organizations of the same country. I want to sum the Value attribute of each Country and put it in a new table.

For example I would like to create:

```
[ { Name: "each Country", Value: "the summed value" } ]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edited to respond to updated question**

You can use [`d3.nest()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#nest) to group objects by a given key (in this case, the country) and then "roll them up" to sum the value across each of the items belonging to a given country. In your case, a one-liner would look something like this:

```
d3.nest().key(function(d){
    return d.organisation.Country; })
.rollup(function(leaves){
    return d3.sum(leaves, function(d){
        return d.Value;
    });
}).entries(data)
.map(function(d){
    return { Country: d.key, Value: d.values};
});
```

Here I'm using [`d3.sum`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#sum), passing in an accessor function to specify that you want to sum the `Value` of each item:

This returns four objects on your example data:

```
[{"Country":"USA","Value":40000},
 {"Country":"France","Value":82000},
 {"Country":"Germany","Value":67000},
 {"Country":"Holland","Value":100000}]
```

Javascript converts the strings into numbers for you. Note that you have some typos in your example data that I had to fix, giving the following:

```
var data = [ { id:0,Department: "Civil",Value : "40000",Title :"Sustainability",ComID : "45", organisation:{ City:"New York",ComID:"45",Country: "USA"}}, { id:1,Department: "Energy",Value : "82000",Title : "Wind Energy",ComID : "62", organisation:{ City:"Paris",ComID:"62",Country: "France"}}, { id:2,Department: "Medical",Value : "67000",Title : "Neuroscience",ComID : "21", organisation:{ City:"Berlin",ComID:"21",Country: "Germany"}}, { id:3,Department: "Computer",Value : "100000",Title : "Security",ComID : "67", organisation:{ City:"Amsterdam",ComID:"67",Country: "Holland"}}]
```

Comment: yeah I have tried with d3.sum but nothing. I have different countries in the dataand I want to sum the values of each country and put it in a new table where I could have for example. new data [ { Country: " ", Value: "the sumed values"}]

Comment: Can you update your question and post more of your data so it's clear what you're trying to do?

Comment: @AkisIoannou: I updated my answer, but the data you posted is still formatted incorrectly.

Comment: Also this link may be useful http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/3176159 Thanks for the example above it was a great help.

Answer (score 3):

Since [`d3-collection`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection) has been deprecated in favor of [`d3.array`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array), we can use [`d3.rollups`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#rollups) to achieve what used to work with `d3.nest`:

```
d3
  .rollups(
    data,
    xs => d3.sum(xs, x => x.Value),
    d => d.organisation.Country
  )
  .map(([k, v]) => ({ Country: k, Value: v }))
```

This:

- Applies a [`d3.rollups`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#rollups):

  - `d3.rollups` takes 3 parameters: the input array, a reducing function and a grouping function
  - `d => d.organisation.Country` groups items by `Country`
  - `xs => d3.sum(xs, x => x.Value)` reduces grouped values by extracting their 
    Value and summing them using [`d3.sum`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#sum)
- Formats the rollups' output in order to get the expected output (the map transformation).

```js
var data = [
  { id: 0, Department: "Civil", Value: "40000", Title:"Sustainability", ComID: "45", organisation: { City: "New York", ComID: 45, Country: "USA" } },
  { id: 1, Department: "Energy", Value: "82000", Title: "Wind Energy", ComID: "62", organisation: { City: "Paris" , ComID: 62, Country: "France" } },
  { id: 2, Department: "Medical", Value: "67000", Title: "Neuroscience", ComID: "21", organisation: { City: "Berlin", ComID: 21, Country: "Germany" } },
  { id: 3, Department: "Computer", Value: "100000", Title: "Security", ComID: "67", organisation: { City: "Amsterdam", ComID: 67, Country: "Holland" } }
];

var output =
  d3.rollups(
      data,
      xs => d3.sum(xs, x => x.Value),
      d => d.organisation.Country
    )
    .map(([k, v]) => ({ Country: k, Value: v }))

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v2.min.js"></script>
```